# vue.jsでの配列への要素の追加方法

Tags: vue.js

テキストに文字を打ちボタンをクリックすると、配列に追加されるようにしたいです。今あるコードですと、テキストに入力した文字が、add function()のpush()の中で追加ができていません。ここで追加するやり方を教えていただきたいです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        sample
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script><!--　type="text/javascript" はなくても動く？-->
    
</head>

<body>
    <h3>好きなプログラミング言語投票</h3>
    <div id="chart_div" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="app">
        <li v-for="(item,c) in dataArray" v-if="c>0">{{item[0]}} : {{item[1]}}
            <button v-on:click="addOne(c)"> 一票</button>
        </li>
        <li><input type="text" v-model="myText" size="5"> <button v-on:click="add">追加</button></li>
    
 
    </div>

    <script>
        //グラフに使うデータ
        var orgdata = [
            ['言語', '票数'],
            ['Java', 1], ['C', 1]
        ];

        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);



        //グラフを表示数関数
        function drawBasic() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(orgdata);
            var options = {title: '好きなプログラミング言語',"is3D": true};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            dataArray:orgdata,
            myText:""
        },
        methods:{
            addOne: function(val){
                var obj = this.dataArray[val];
                obj[1]++;
                this.dataArray.splice(val,1,obj);
                drawBasic();
            },add: function () {//配列に追加するときのメソッド
                    this.orgdata.push([this.myText,1]);//TODO
            }


                
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

当該インスタンスにデータ、`this.orgdata`は存在しないように見えます。`this.dataArray`の誤りであったりしませんか？
またブラウザのコンソールにエラーが出ていませんか？